# Android two MediaPlayers at the same time skipping

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, video-processing

I have an app which plays two videos at the same time. On a MotoG (Android 4.4.4) if the app is playing two videos which were generated on an Android device, it works fine. If it is playing a single video generated on iOS, it works fine.

But if it is playing 1 video generated on iOS and a second video from either iOS or Android, the player goes crazy and skips and stutters and just doesn't play back properly.

There is a minor difference between the two file formats, but since both files play properly by themselves, I think this is something that should be working on Android. Below is the ffmpeg info for the different video files.

In case it makes a difference, the `MediaPlayers` are hooked up to display on a `SurfaceHolder` which comes from a `SurfaceView` in the layout xml.

Any help would be appreciated!

File created on iOS:
`Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'createdOnIOS.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2015-02-20 08:01:30
  Duration: 00:00:06.34, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1577 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 360x480, 1509 kb/s, 29.98 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-20 08:01:30
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 63 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-20 08:01:30
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio`

File created on Android:
`Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'createdOnAndroid.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2015-02-20 08:10:17
  Duration: 00:00:06.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6096 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480, 6002 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 3:2, 24.68 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2015-02-20 08:10:17
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      encoder         : MOTO
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-20 08:10:17
      handler_name    : SoundHandle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! (Well sort of.)

On the android `MediaPlayer` there is a callback for `OnVideoSizeChanged`. I use that callback to adjust the UI to make sure the video aspect ratio displays correctly. For some reason, on the iOS videos, adjusting the size of video view was causing `OnVideoSizeChanged` to get called again. Which was causing the views to get updated, which was calling `OnVideoSizeChanged`... and thus causing the view to not have good performance.

In short, the fix was:

```
public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height)
{
  if(mViewSize == null || mViewSize.x != width ||
                          mViewSize.y != height)
  {
    mViewSize = new Point(width, height);
    updateViews();
  }
}
```

I'm still not sure why the android videos weren't causing this behavior, but at least I figured out how to fix my immediate issue.